# Multithreaded VB.NET SQL Application throws exception

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, multithreading

I've been developing an application with VB.NET that will be executed daily. This application should throw a series of SQL queries(that execute the same stored procedure), process the retrieved data and then dump it to a file. As each query corresponds to a single, independent file, I'm trying to improving it by launching each "query-process-write to file" in a single thread.

The problem here is that SQL is throwing an "ODBC does not support the requested properties" exception in two of the greatest queries. If I try to run it in SQL Management Studio, it works fine (it's lasting about 30 secs and retrieving about 30k long registers).

I'm using System.Thread methods to queue each thread in a List(of Thread), then starting them with their corresponding parameters. Also tried with a Thread Pool, getting the same result. I've included a critical section in the query execution (blocking the ADO recordset and connection objects either with SyncLock and Monitor). I'm checking the recordset to be open and not null, but I'm getting the same exception every time.

I've opened the Activity Monitor in the corresponding SQL Database, in case that all those queries may be consuming too many resources, but everything seems to be working fine. I've also modified the program to be single-threaded and I get the same error. But, as I said, if I copy **exactly the same** query (while debugging the program) , everything works fine.

Any ideas? (Sorry for my English)

Comment: Are you using MySQL oder SQL-Server? Please edit your tags.

Comment: @muffi SQL Server! Sorry

Comment: Why are you using *ODBC* to connect to SQL Server? And what is the *problem*? Obviously, VB.NET works just fine with SQL Server, otherwise someone would have noticed in the past 17 years. Post the *actual code*, connection string and full exception, as returned by `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: BTW 30 seconds for only 30K queries is awful. You probably have performance issues already - missing indexes, bad query. Multithreading isn't going to make a bad query run any faster

Comment: And finally, ADO.NET already has true asynchronous methods. `ExecuteReaderAsync`, `ExecuteScalarAsync` are already asynchronous. You don't need extra threads

Comment: Post the actual code, not your description of it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your edit and answers. About ODBC, I inherited part of the code and it was the method that was being use. Which method do you think that I should be using?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that 30s for this is too much. I'm trying to improve it. Those 30s include a subquery to another table and a complete sort of the 30k registers, perhaps that's the reason why it lasts so long.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos by now, I've removed the subquery and changed an obsolete type (text to varchar). About the asyncronous methods, I don't really understand your point. I'm launching a thread for every query because I can short the process and I/O time if I make it like that. But I'll try to use those methods you mention.